# Json Modeling in Java from Api call

Tags: java, android, json

I am making a call to the Steam Storefront api and am trying to model the data in java but am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do so because of a slight issue.

So, say you make a call Appid 57690 = Tropico 4

http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690

It will return with the header {"57690": {... rest of json }}

But if you make the call to Appid 570 = Dota 2

http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=570

It will return with the header {"570": {... rest of json }}

How do you create the POJO's to model this, because it is a header?

Comment: The root is just a String..

Comment: Question: What are you exactly using to read/write objects from/into JSON data?

Comment: I plan on using retrofit @DragShot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a class, inside add one property of type "String" and then an object for the rest of the JSON.

For example

```
public class MyClass{
  public String rootId = "";
  public SteamObj steamObj = new SteamObj();
}

public class SteamObj {
  //Who knows what
}
```

Either way you can make use of this tool to generate the POJO for you:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Oh okay for some reason I had in my head that there needed to be a static, unchanging name like "Response" or "Message" at the header of a Json file, thanks for clearing that up